# Ubuntu 10.0 sound muted automatically on ThinkPad

Tags: ubuntu, audio, thinkpad

My laptop is ThinkPad T61, with Ubuntu 10.10 installed. The sound works all well, until I plugged the Creative XiFi Go USB sound card. After I reboot my computer, the internal speaker is muted automatically. I have to use 'alsamixer' to unmute it each time. How can I persistent this setting?

Comment: @Alaukik: although Ubuntu is the distribution involved, this isn't particularly Ubuntu-specific. When questions and answers could be generally useful to people not running Ubuntu, they're better here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you want to execute is:

`amixer sset Master 50%`

To have it run when you login, add it to `System > Preferences > Startup Applications` as the command.

To have it run at boot time, add it to your `/etc/rc.local` file.

Comment: I have tried this before. But my question is why this happens only after I used my USB sound card? There must be something wrong in the System setting.